Windows 11 seems to have disabled all ways to get around Auto Update Restarts. Is there a workaround?
I run Matlab simulations that sometimes take weeks to finish and when Windows restarts I lose all my work so I really need a way to stop auto restarts.
Windows 11 seems to have disabled all ways to get around Auto Update Restarts. Is there a still a workaround?
It used to be possible to set NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers in:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU
if you also set AUOptions to 4 in the same location but this does not work for me now.

The only way I know to delay an automatic reboot caused by a pending Windows Update update, is to manually or automatically adjust the activity hours, every 12 hours. NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers hasn’t been enough to prevent an automated reboot since Windows 10 was released


Make sure there are no pending updates before you start, then, 2. Disconnect the PC from the internet. On Windows 10 machine, one can set Ethernet, as well as WiFi, metered (https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/ethernet-metered-connection-windows-10-defaultmediacost/), but on Win 11, one might need to use Airplane Mode. [When "metered" is used, updates on Win 10 are not automatic, but internet is available.]


Matlab works on Linux too... more workaround than this ! :-).
By the way, for simulations that run for a long time it is common practice to dump the data and save the restart file every xx minutes, where xx is the amount of (simulation) time you are willing to lose. Usually we go by trial and error to translate the simulation time (MD) or the number of steps (MC) into human time...

@Hastur. Yes, its a good reason to say bye bye to Windows. I would love to be able to save a restart file but they are usually very complex simulations with lots of complex states that it would be very difficult to get back to without running from the start again.

Another workaround. Run the simulation in a virtual machine. Set the virtual machine to freeze (save state on the hdd) when receives the shutdown and to restart automatically after the reboot. Increase the grace time on the host for the reboot to allow the guest machine to save the status. You should not lose more than 10% of the time. I always run simulations on linux/BSD machine...

@MichaelMcLaughlin You should add your own answer for the solution you found, probably with an acknowledgment of Ramhound's comment. You can accept it too, if you want: Can I answer my own question?

I was going to suggest the method suggested by @DrMoishePippik but he beat me to it. If the system has nothing to use to do an update with you'd hope that it would not try. One can hope :-)

You mean you don't turn off Automatic Updates by placing a deny execute ACL on the service binary?

@MichaelMcLaughlin My question has received 3 downvotes. Is there any way to find out why? I don't know for sure, but I suspect those downvotes were from people who think that you should not be deferring updates no matter what, people who feel that updates are so important that they outweigh actually getting work done.  (And yes, I know, updates are important, because security vulnerabilities are Bad.  The question is, of course, what balance to strike between uptime and safety.)

What Windows 11 edition are you running on?  Windows 11 Pro?  Home? Enterprise? Enterprise LTSC?  Something else?

How do you handle power outages?

@d-b UPS and generators. Those failures occur far less than once a month.

@SteveSummit I agree. I know updates are very important, and I make sure to keep updated, but I don't like being treated like a child. I need to ALWAYS have the power to defer updates until the time is right for me.

Windows Update first came out as part of Windows 98, and it made you reboot for updates.  Microsoft has had over a quarter-century to fix reboots, and instead they've doubled down on them more and more with every new version over the past decade or so. If the computer ever, ever for any reason, reboots without the owner's explicit consent, that is a massive failure, particularly given that the technical problem they're solving by reboots isn't that difficult to work around. There's no good reason why you should have to reboot to install an update. How have they not been sued over this yet?

While I don't know Win11, according to this recent article, https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-stop-updates-windows-11/, it still appears to have the pause option where you can pause updates for up to 5 weeks. If your "weeks" is shorter than that, this may be enough already. This screenshot in particular: https://static1.xdaimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/wm/2024/02/windows-11-stop-updates-2.png

Who's going to tell Microsoft that Availability is one of the 3 pillars of information security? Not an argument that will provide a workaround in this particular instance, but should carry weight in the long run.

Windows will not reboot during working hours. My solution is to run a scheduled task that changes the working hours in the registry, say every hour or two, so that it is never not a working hour. I coded up this 4 line cmd command batch file program:
for /f %%i in ('powershell "((get-date).Hour+18) %% 24"') do set startHour=%%i
for /f %%i in ('powershell "((get-date).Hour+12) %% 24"') do set endHour=%%i

reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings /v ActiveHoursStart /t REG_DWORD /d %startHour% /f 
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings /v ActiveHoursEnd /t REG_DWORD /d %endHour% /f  

I then used Windows Task Scheduler to make this .bat script run every hour for 1 day and repeat daily.
To stop pop-ups of the command windows, make task scheduler start the program/script "cmd.exe"
and put as it's arguments:
/c start /min C:\work\disableautoupdate.bat ^& exit
(Substitute your own filename above for C:\work\disableautoupdate.bat)
This will minimise the window your script runs in.

Tested: It works! I installed an update requiring a restart on 31-May. I am informed that this restart will happen outside of working hours. As of 20-June, 22 days later, no restart had taken place.
I figured out how to incorporate @Jonathan's feedback. It is easier to do modulo maths (and to get the hour independent of locale/region/format preferences) with powershell commands. It's still a cmd batch file, but it calls powershell. Reduces to 4 lines and should work everywhere.

Cool hack! Please let us know whether it works... BTW, you can do the hour logic much more easily in PowerShell: $currentHour = (get-date).Hour; $startHour = ($currentHour+18) % 24; $endHour = ($currentHour+6) % 24

I tried out this script and it seems to work well, just two problems:

it doesn't work in the AM if the time format is HH, because it doesn't recognise, say, 08 as an int to add.
Evil Windows Update has now started inserting Scheduled Tasks to wake up my PC and reboot it at the end of the active hours, so it won't stay asleep anymore!


@MichaelMcLaughlin huh, weird that yours works and mine doesn't! 08 is not GTR 5 for me, then it tries to run set /a startHour = 08+18 and fails with Invalid number error.

@Coxy correct, 08 and 09 are invalid octal numbers. Just run set /a 08 or set /a 09 to see. You always need to drop the leading zeros for it to work

@MichaelMcLaughlin time/t is a terrible way to get time, because it's locale dependent like %date% or %time%. Just avoid it and use wmic for a locale independent time or move to powershell where almost everything is simpler

Thanks @puclv, I changed the batch to use for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1" %%g in (\wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Hour ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do set currentHour=%%g` and from my testing it should work before 1000.

v2 (I think it makes slightly more sense to use the regex to find the hour): for /f "usebackq tokens=1" %%g in (\wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Hour ^| findstr /R "[0-9][0-9]^*"`) do set currentHour=%%g`

@phuclv Why would I not want local time?

@Coxy. On second thoughts, you are correct about leading zeros for 8 and 9.

@MichaelMcLaughlin local or UTC is irrelevant, obviously with wmic you can get both times. It's the format of the time command and %time% isn't consistent so the first token might not be hour at all, and it might result in leading zero in many locales which completely break the command, don't you see?

@phuclv It seems like wmic is Deprecated and will soon be removed. I toyed with powershell for a while but got disillusioned with it when I realised that you can't reliably double click a powershell script to run it. You have to jump through hoops to setup your machine so that it can be double clicked

@MichaelMcLaughlin it's just one command to the setup the execution policy if necessary, and it's done only once. It's also possible to use various flags to disable unnecessary things when starting up a powershell script. There are less things to learn than the tricky legacy of cmd. Your command will break in locales that don't use AM/PM (actually most of the locales out there), or locales that don't use Latin digits

@phuclv You confused me. I thought you were talking about wmic. Now I see what you are saying. Yes, perhaps it is just one command to allow double clicking to run PowerShell commands. The problem is that I can never remember what that command is (or I forget that actually I need to use a command) and then I need to Google it, I inevitably get it wrong, I get frustrated, I Google it again, etc. so it means that my utilities are not portable between machines if I use PowerShell for them.

First, excellent work, this is simplicity and efficiency. Second, screw Microsoft for making us have to jump through hoops to keep Updates from happening when WE need them to.

Windows actually has an API that enables a process that has a window to block a system shutdown indefinitely until the user manually chooses what to do next. (possibly, as @josh3736
pointed out, Windows Update may break this eventually. But I personally have not experienced a concrete case of it. At least it should be safe to block a shutdown when you sleep until you wake up, and then you just click cancel to cancel the shutdown)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasoncreate

ShutdownBlockReasonCreate function (winuser.h)
Indicates that the system cannot be shut down and sets a reason string to be displayed to the user if system shutdown is initiated.

Note that calling this alone cannot block a shutdown/restart successfully. You also need your application to handle the WM_QUERYENDSESSION and WM_ENDSESSION messages. I will discuss them at the end.
If you are not a developer so you do not know how to use Windows API, you can use a small program that I have written years ago for exactly the same purpose: https://github.com/real-guanyuming-he/ShutdownBlocker
Either way, when you have successfully created a shutdown block reason, Windows will pause when a shutdown (including an update restart) is issued, and display this to you, where you can click Cancel to cancel the shutdown.

Note: If you have no control over your Matlab simulations program (I do not use Matlab so I do not know if it is possible), then it might or might not work, depending on how Matlab handles the situation. According to Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/shutting-down),

Applications with a window and message queue receive shutdown notifications through the WM_QUERYENDSESSION and WM_ENDSESSION messages. These applications should return TRUE to indicate that they can be terminated.

If Matlab chooses to return TRUE on receiving this message, it will close, even if the shutdown is blocked this way. (And if you call the API without returning FALSE on receiving WM_QUERYENDSESSION, then it will not succeed as your app would close as a result of it)

I don't think this particular API will be all that helpful.  Note that ShutdownBlockReasonCreate simply sets the string that shows up in the shutdown UI (the one pictured in your screenshot); calling the method does not actually prevent shutdown from occurring.  To prevent shutdown, you have to have an open window and return FALSE when you receive WM_QUERYENDSESSION.  However, even if you do that, it's my impression that Windows Update gets aggressive and eventually forces a restart anyway, ignoring apps that try to prevent it.

…so the best thing to do is to use the Group Policy setting mentioned above.

@josh3736 My program does return FALSE on receiving WM_QUERYENDSESSION. I haven't been using it recently, but about one year ago, it could block an update that happened at midnight all the way until I woke up in the morning. Do not know if Microsoft will play some evil trick to force the restart continue anyway after a longer time.

Right, the WM_QUERYENDSESSION return value is the part that actually prevents shutdown.  I'm just pointing out that ShutdownBlockReasonCreate is entirely informational, and contrary to what this answer says, calling it does not actually do anything to prevent a system shutdown.

That said, I know that returning false from WM_QUERYENDSESSION won't prevent a reboot indefinitely either.  Eventually, Windows Update will force a restart anyway, which is why there's so much complaining about this on the internet.

What may make this less useful is the small detail that seeing a message about one process blocking a restart doesn't necessarily mean that the other processes - including Matlab - aren't gone already. Win10 usually has a Cancel button on this screen letting you go back and handle the application yourself, and then you can see that everything else is closed.

@tevemadar I mentioned that at the end of my answer.

The Group Policy Configure Automatic Updates allows you to prevent automatic installation of updates.

Open gpedit.msc
Computer -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update -> Manage end user experience -> Configure Automatic Updates (Alternatively go through "all settings" if you use English and you know the name from here)
Enable, Set to (2) notify only


Specifies whether this computer will receive security updates and other important downloads through the Windows automatic updating service.
This setting lets you specify whether automatic updates are enabled on this computer. If the service is enabled, you must select one of the four options in the Group Policy Setting:
2 = Notify before downloading and installing any updates.
When Windows finds updates that apply to this computer, users will be notified that updates are ready to be downloaded. After going to Windows Update, users can download and install any available updates.


Is GP still limited to "Pro" versions and not available on "Home" (assuming that silliness still exists in Windows 11)?

My understanding is that even Pro editions of Windows will ignore this Group Policy settings. The OP would have to pirate an Enterprise edition of Windows.

@Coxy IME that's not true. The policy works fine on Pro.

@millebi Yes, the Group Policy Editor is not available in the Home editions of Windows, but from Professional upwards. The Group Policy Editor is a frontend to the registry settings though, so you should be able to set the appropriate registry directly as an alternative on Home editions.

@Coxy That setting specifically, or any setting that is listed in group policies? Why would Professional have the editor for it then?

@Kissaki Pro has the policy editor, and Home does not.

@Kissaki several GPOs are limited to Enterprise only, like "Turn off Microsoft consumer experiences". Pro still contains the GPO editor, and could be managing (domain) GPO which applies to an Enterprise computer. MS generally maintains a single set of GPO templates for each OS, even though different SKUs might have varying support. -- However, this policy's help text does not mention anything about only working on Enterprise.

There is no setting Computer -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update -> Manage end user experience -> Configure Automatic Updates in recent version of Windows 11 :(

@EugeneMala I still see it on the current Windows 11 version 23H2 (Professional edition).
